# Why first elements in recycler view displayed incorrectly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Now I writing my small game "Bulls and Cows". I added to the bottom of my layout recycler view and write sample code to test it:

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(this, null)
turnStory.adapter = adapter
repeat(100) {
adapter.updateData(Triple("test$it", "test$it", "test$it")
}
```

I started my activity on the phone and [saw that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiiGl.png)

But when I scrolled down and scrolled back [everything became normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Nww.png)

MyAdapter.kt

```
class MyAdapter(private val ctx: Context, private val data: Triple<String, String, String>?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

private val dataset = mutableListOf<Triple<String, String, String>>()
init {
    if (data != null) dataset.add(data)
}

class MyViewHolder(val frameLayout: FrameLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(frameLayout)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val frameLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.frame_layout, parent, false) as FrameLayout

    return MyViewHolder(frameLayout)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.frameLayout.numberView.text = dataset[position].first

    holder.frameLayout.bullsView.text =
        ctx.resources.getString(R.string.bulls_counter, dataset[position].second)
    holder.frameLayout.cowsView.text =
        ctx.resources.getString(R.string.cows_counter, dataset[position].third)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size

fun updateData(data: Triple<String, String, String>) {
    dataset.add(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

`}`

frame_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:autoSizeTextType="none" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bullsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cowsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Why first elements in recycler view displayed incorrectly before I scroll down?

computer_game_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GameComputerActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/turnStory"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: is your recyclerview width set to match_parent or wrap_content?

Comment: @A.easazadeh match_parent

Comment: try setting it to a fixed value like 360. see if you still have the issue. if you still have then the problem is in the layout that you placed your recyclerview in

Comment: @ВасилийКурагов Try using wrap_content instead of android:layout_height="100dp" in FrameLayout

Comment: @A.easazadeh, I set fixed value and my recycler view began to work fine. But as far as I know fixed value isn t good because my app won't work well on devices with small screens.

Comment: can you share the code of the layout your recyclerview is in

Comment: add `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, it should move it to top

Comment: you just change computer_game_activity.xml

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/turnStory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />